# Replace values in column of a dataframe when matching to column in another dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

I just read through comparable questions, but found no answering my specific problem.
I have two dataframes,

```
df1 <- data.frame("name" = c("11-24", "Tim", "Anna", "67-14", "A0839", "A4b", "Lisa", "Selina"))
df2 <- data.frame("abbreviation" = c("11-24", "67-14", "A0839", "A4b"),
                  "name" = c("Charles", "Nick", "Harry", "Lola"))
```

Looking like this:

```
> df1
    name
1  11-24
2    Tim
3   Anna
4  67-14
5  A0839
6    A4b
7   Lisa
8 Selina

> df2
  abbreviation    name
1        11-24 Charles
2        67-14    Nick
3        A0839   Harry
4          A4b    Lola
```

I want to replace the abbreviations found in the column "name" of df1 by the matching name in df2.
So that 11-24 is replaced by Charles or A4b by Lola.

What I tried was:

```
df1 <- df1 %>% 
       mutate(name = ifelse(name %in% df2$abbreviation, df2$name, name))
```

But this give not the result I want.
I want:

```
> df1
        name
    1Charles
    2    Tim
    3   Anna
    4   Nick
    5  Harry
    6   Lola
    7   Lisa
    8 Selina
```

My dataframes have a different length.
I am looking for a tidyverse-solution, maybe one of you has something in mind..

This would help me a lot :)
Best,
Kathrin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R solution:

```
idx <- match(df1$name, df2$abbreviation)
transform(df1, name = ifelse(!is.na(idx), df2$name[idx], name))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using join and `coalesce`.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c('name' = 'abbreviation')) %>%
  transmute(name = coalesce(name.y, name))

#     name
#1 Charles
#2     Tim
#3    Anna
#4    Nick
#5   Harry
#6    Lola
#7    Lisa
#8  Selina
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I don't know why but I thought that left_join will not.. This helped me :)

Answer (score 1):

In *base* you can use `match` to make this *update join*.

```
idx <- match(df1$name, df2$abbreviation)
idxn <- which(!is.na(idx))
#idxn <- !is.na(idx) #Alternative
df1$name[idxn] <- df2$name[idx[idxn]]
df1
#     name
#1 Charles
#2     Tim
#3    Anna
#4    Nick
#5   Harry
#6    Lola
#7    Lisa
#8  Selina
```